# in section Materials the Mesh's Emission mixes the colors how to fix it?

Tags: rendering, mesh, materials, emission

I want to glow the mesh plane, when I illuminate an area by the glowing mesh, the light spoils the environment where it meets, it's blurring and blending colors together. I'm in section materials and and I have indicated emission on the mesh plane which has to glow. what is the problem?
[image]

---

[image]

I set the strength to this level (you'll see on new screenshot) to be noticeable. 1.0 strength has the same defect. I turned off the main light.

I watch a tutorial where the mesh shines quite strongly and illuminates a specific area. don't understand what's wrong with my mesh

[image]

Comment: Hi, Sophia, and welcome. A first suggestion for easier diagnosis might be to temporarily disable all other light-sources, (including the World) so you can see the contribution the plane is making, on its own.

Comment: What happens if you start out with a lower Strength, say less than 1.0 ?  If that doesn't work, edit this information into your question.

Comment: Hi Robin thanks for responding. So I tried it with low power but it still has a defect. :(